# javascript: problems with variable scope. Can't access outside variable inside jquery event

Tags: javascript

Inside a JS file I have this:

```
task_categories = new CategoryTree();

$('input:radio[name=what_tasks]').click(function () {
    var where = getLocation();
    taskList(where.project, task_categories.selected_elements, where.page);
});
```

Firefox debugger won't complain me trying to access task_categories but unfortunately, task_categories will be undefined.

How can I make this work? Thanks!

Comment: show **CategoryTree** definition

Comment: `var task_categories = new CategoryTree();` ?

Comment: also, show what tasklist is doing; one more thing, using `where` as a variable name is a big no-no, it is a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: task_categories can be defined elsewhere, but the assignment is probably undefined which is why you would get an error. if you try `task_categories = {}` the error should go away. (although `.selected_elements` will be undefined

Comment: Um, in the code sample, it should be fine. Is that exactly how the code looks like? Is the variable changed before the click event?

Comment: task_categories won't be accessed until the click event happens.  Do you set it to undefined at a later point in the code?

Comment: perhaps you overwrite the (possibly accidentally global) variable later?

Comment: I fixed it by having this.selected_elements in CategoryTree instead of var selected_elements. I still don't understand when to use this or var I'm affraid.

Comment: @SrgHartman: Then [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object/13418980#13418980) might help you